# Can you build blocks with cube? inductive proof

Tags: geometry, analysis, proof-writing, induction

The cube $S$ with side $2$ consists of $8$ unit cubes.

Define *block* a figure that is formed from a cube $S$ as a result of the removal of one unit cube.

Decide if the cube with dimensions $2^n\cdot 2^n\cdot 2^n$ from which one cube has been removed can be built by *blocks*.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the OP at first I've revised that. Note that if you are just interested to the solution you can find easily many duplicates here on MSE otherwise try to follow the given hint and show your work here.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Since a block is formed by $7$ unit cubes we just need to prove that

$$7|2^{3n}-1=8^n-1$$

if you want to proceed by induction let consider

- base case: $n=1$
- induction step: assuming $7|8^n-1$ prove that $7|8^{n+1}-1$

Comment: Yes, I thought you must have misunderstood what the questioner was asking. Now that you have re-written your answer, my comment no longer applies so I will delete it. BTW, $7|8^n-1$ is a necessary condition for a solution, but I don't think on its own it is a sufficient condition.